Regular Expression MS-SQL Starts with RI and followed by two more defined characters and a space
I have a column that is a string and I want to find all records where the string starts with one of the following:
'RIRV', 'RIUI', 'RIRI', 'RICJ', 'RIRE', 'RIRF', 'RIAW', 'RIAS', 'RINA'
So they all start RI and must be followed by: 'RV|UI|CJ|RE|RF|AW|AS|NA) %'
I was using:
WHERE SUBSTRING(A.[pa-smart-comment], 1, 5) IN (
            'RIRV ', 'RIUI ', 'RIRI ', 'RICJ ', 'RIRE ','RIRF ','RIAW ','RIAS ','RINA '
            )

But I find the LIKE to be faster in use.

SQL Server doesn't have regular expressions. LIKE uses simple wildcard matches, not regular expressions. In general it's a bad idea to use substring searches in SQL because they can't use any indexes but prefix searches are essentially range searches that can take advantage of indexing

Ok thank you very much. I'll use my original method or try to adapt something a little faster.

What are the actual data? What do they represent? If you use comment LIKE 'RIRV%' OR comment like 'RIUI%' OR .... you could take advantage of indexes. Each of those LIKE operations translates to comment >='RIRV' and comment < 'RIRW' etc. If those strings represent flags or hierarchies though, it would be a LOT faster to use separate columns and indexes

Data would look like 'RIUI %' etc where there is a space after the code followed by whatever the message is

And why does the data look like this? What's the significance of RI and UI? Why is there a RI and a RV? If these represent categories, a far better solution would be to have separate columns. You could write where category='RI' and subcategory IN ('UI','RV',....) and get a far faster and far simpler query.

RI represents a department and the two characters that follow represent an issue. But there is no possibility to have two separate columns. I'm working with a 40yo+ system

SQL Server isn't 40 years old and this rule, the 1st Normal Form, is the most fundamental design rule for RDBMS systems. Someone may have migrated a 40 year old system to a relational database but that doesn't make the bad "smart" key a good or acceptable solution. Either you fix it, or you type long and slow queries

The system that feeds the db is - updating that system funcationality is also not an option, replacing that system comes at a cost of ten's of millions.

The DB isn't. And the DB should be properly designed. That's the job of all ETL or data integration systems, to load data that may be in pretty bad shape, clean it up and convert it to a form that's appropriate for querying, reporting or any other kind of use. The easiest solution would be to modify whatever loads the data to split the not-so-smart field into separate fields. Next best is to use computed columns to extract the parts as separate fields and index them, eg Category AS LEFT(comment,2), SubCategory as SUBSTRING(comment,3,2).

I hear what your saying, that current system is going away, and modifications to it are not going to be entertained.

I'm importing some pretty mangled data right now into tables with millions of rows. Part of the job is to actually clean up the data and split it into proper tables with proper indexes. There's no way I could query those if I kept the mangled data as is. I wouldn't be able to use any indexes. Imagine trying to join tables with just 1K rows each - that's 1M comparisons

If you can't clean up the data the only solution is to use multiple LIKE 'prefix%' operations . Applying any function to the field prevents the server from using indexes. The indexes are created using the stored values and can't be used to speed up searches using unknown function results

Combine a sarg-able LIKE with whatever you want to narrow the results.  This will allow SQL to efficiently eliminate the rows not starting with 'RI' and having a space after the first 4 characters.
WHERE A.[pa-smart-comment] like 'RI__ %'
  and SUBSTRING(A.[pa-smart-comment], 1, 4) IN (
            'RIRV', 'RIUI', 'RIRI', 'RICJ', 'RIRE','RIRF','RIAW','RIAS','RINA'
            )


